# How can I pause spawning in a coroutine until all the spawned objects are destroyed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I just don't know how to write the if part. The rest is just instantiate position and quaternion stuff.... Probably.

I want to know if the GameObject rocketspawnblue and  GameObject rocketspawnred are gone, so I can spawn the next pair until all the pairs in the loop are spawned.

This is my spawning coroutine I put in `Start()`. however that's probably won't work because it needs to be check every frame until i take all my rockets....

```
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    GameObject rocketspawnblue = Instantiate(
            rocketblue, 
            new Vector3(Random.Range(-15, 15), (Random.Range(-15, 15))), 
            Quaternion.identity);
    SpriteRenderer rocketscolor1 = rocketspawnblue.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    //rocketscolor.color = colors[Random.Range(0,colors.Length)];
    rocketscolor1.color = Color.blue;

    GameObject rocketspawnred = Instantiate(
            rocketred, 
            new Vector3(Random.Range(-15, 15), (Random.Range(-15, 15))), 
            Quaternion.identity);
    SpriteRenderer rocketscolor2 = rocketspawnred.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    //rocketscolor.color = colors[Random.Range(0, colors.Length)];
    rocketscolor2.color = Color.red;
}
```

Comment: You will have to call this coroutine once from `Update` but then it will check occasionally on its own, depending on how it's written. If you need help calling it exactly once that would be best for another question.

Comment: Why just not left it on the start ?

Comment: You can leave it in Start if you only want to spawn the batch once per time the object is instantiated. As long as you only have one instance of the coroutine active at a time, it will be fine.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `List` as a field to track the rockets:

```
private List<GameObject> rockets;
```

At the beginning of `Start()`, instantiate the list:

```
rockets = new List<GameObject>();
```

In your coroutine, clear the list with `Clear` then use `Add` to add rockets to your list. After you're done adding, use `WaitWhile` to loop until there are no rockets left. We'll write a method called `AnyRocketsLeft` that returns true if there are any that are not yet destroyed.

After the `WaitWhile`, use `WaitForSeconds` to wait for a second to give time between batches.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
    rockets.Clear();
    GameObject rocketspawnblue = Instantiate(
            rocketblue, 
            new Vector3(Random.Range(-15, 15), (Random.Range(-15, 15))), 
            Quaternion.identity);
    SpriteRenderer rocketscolor1 = rocketspawnblue.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    //rocketscolor.color = colors[Random.Range(0,colors.Length)];
    rocketscolor1.color = Color.blue;
    rockets.Add(rocketspawnblue);

    GameObject rocketspawnred = Instantiate(
            rocketred, 
            new Vector3(Random.Range(-15, 15), (Random.Range(-15, 15))), 
            Quaternion.identity);
    SpriteRenderer rocketscolor2 = rocketspawnred.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    //rocketscolor.color = colors[Random.Range(0, colors.Length)];
    rocketscolor2.color = Color.red;
    rockets.Add(rocketspawnred);

    yield return new WaitWhile(() => AnyRocketsLeft());
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
}

// ran out of rockets
// set up the "next level" prompt, etc. here
```

To check if any rockets are not yet destroyed, we can check their `activeInHierarchy` property. Just loop through the list of rockets and return true if you find any, and false otherwise.

```
private bool AnyRocketsLeft() {
    foreach (int i = 0 ; i < rockets.count ; i++) {
        if (rockets[i].activeInHierarchy) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you're using Linq, you can use List.Any():

```
private bool AnyRocketsLeft() {
    return rockets.Any(o => o.activeInHierarchy);
}
```

Comment: Might want to add that you can call out to AnyRocketsLeft from the Update method.

Comment: @TonyAbrams I'm 99% sure I misunderstood the intent before. With these changes it makes more sense to call it in the coroutine like so.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: Wouldn't you agree this would look better with `yield return new WaitUntil(() => AnyRocketsLeft())`?

Comment: I did not know about `WaitUntil` or `WaitWhile`! Thank you for bringing that to my attention. I will add that. I think Asker may want a brief pause between clearing out the rockets and the next pair spawning, so I will still have a WaitForSeconds call in there just for that.

Comment: @FredrikSchön I think you meant `WaitWhile` in your comment there. ;) But yeah, `WaitWhile` and `WaitUntil` are the weird black sheep of the coroutine system, because you never see them in examples. And of course, you could simplify again to `WaitWhile(() => rockets.Any(o => o.activeInHierarchy));`

Comment: Oh yeah, that's right. Thanks for the correction! I find it humorous that there is both a WaitWhile & a WaitUntil, I'd probably have done it `WaitUntil(() => !AnyRocketsLeft());` as a petty objection against `WaitWhile`'s existance.

Comment: @FredrikSchön to me it sounds the other way round actually: Instead of using `WaitUntil(something)` to me it sounds more obvious using `WaitWhile(! something)` ;) Especially since it is like a shorthand for `do { yield return null; } while(!something);` but there is no `do{ yield return null; } until(something);` afaik